# How to force render docx as text but not table in Telerik Reporting docx

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, docx, telerik-reporting

I have a problem with Telerik Reporting which I don't know how to solve. When I try to export a report in DOCX format it renders content as table. I would like to render the content as just text. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunatly not possible. From [Design Considerations for Word Rendering](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports-considerations-word):

> Report exported to Word appears as a nested table that represents both
> the report layout and content.

This means that every element in the report will be a table, and if you have an element within another element, it will be another table inside a table in the word document. The value of your element will be the content of the table.